# Converting UIView to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I've done this before but I have no idea what I'm missing.

I started the project as a single View project.

Then converted the ViewController to inherit from UITableViewController like so:

```
 @interface ViewController : UITableViewController
```

went into the .xib for this ViewController and changed the class in the Custom Class section form UIView to UITableView:

[image]

Looking in my other project(s) where the ViewControllers are just straight TableView controllers, I don't see what else needs to be done, but when I run the app or when I view the xib it's not showing a tableview.

Comment: Where are you testing your app?

Comment: what you probably want to do is: create a custom class inherited from UITableViewController and use this class in the custom class section (e.g. MyTableViewController)

Comment: Yeah, basically I have to just create a new class, and do as you stated, have it inherit from UITableViewController, and the wire up is already done, including in the .xib (as long as you check create .xib in the wizard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to drag out a UITableView in Interface Builder to replace the UIView. Then add the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols to your view controllers header file and connect the datasource and delegate outlets from your UITableView to your view controller in Interface Builder.

```
 @interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Comment: thanks, frustrating though I know I was able to do it in the past without setting the delegate or the datasource (unless it eventually needed it).

Answer (score 0):

add delegate & dataSource. i think you are forgotten to add delegates &dataSource thats why its not showing table. add following lines to your viewDidLoad().

```
 self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
  self.myTableView.delegate = self;
```

after this also implements the required methods of delegate, that are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
 return 1;
}


- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
 return
 10; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//your code for cell data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What init method are you using in the .m file. You need to use the

```
[[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain]
```

allocation method and make sure you have included the`<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>` and the relevant datasource and delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

basically, if you want to just have a UITableViewController from scratch without having to manually do the above, just create a new Obj-C class, have it inherit from UITableViewController, and select to create a xib, and it will give you a viewcontroller and view already wired to working with a UITableView:

[image]

[image]